# Want to have Django From dropdown filtered by logged-in User (Customer), using __init__ method

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Want to have Django From dropdown filtered by logged-in User (Customer), using `__init__` method. But when submit the form, keep having this Field `id` expected a number but got <QueryDict: { error:

```
class OrderForm(ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['contract', 'quantity', 'status']
        
    
    def __init__(self, customer, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['contract'].queryset = Contract.objects.filter(customer=customer)
    


@login_required(login_url='login')
def createOrder(request):

    customer = request.user.customer.id

    form = OrderForm(customer)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.customer = request.user.customer
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Ticket submitted successfully .')
            return redirect('customer_table')

    context = {'form':form}

    return render(request, 'create-order.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass any attribute in form like this

in view:

```
   form = OrderForm(request.POST, customer=request.user)
```

in form:

```
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        customer = kwargs.pop('user') # allway before super() 
         # and call .pop() not .get() on kwargs, for upper class not evaluate user keyword

        super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['contract'].queryset = Contract.objects.filter(customer=customer)
```

Comment: Problem solved, thank you. The main point is to put 'customer = kwargs.pop('user')' before the super ( ).

Answer (score 0):

I summarize the working solutions as below:

View.py

def createOrder(request):

```
form = OrderForm(request.POST, customer=request.user.customer.id)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OrderForm(request.POST, customer=request.user.customer.id)
    if form.is_valid():
        form = form.save(commit=False)
        form.customer = request.user.customer
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Ticket submitted successfully .')
        return redirect('customer_table')

context = {'form':form}

return render(request, 'create-order.html', context)
```

class OrderForm(ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = Order
    fields = ['contract', 'quantity', 'status']


def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    customer = kwargs.pop('customer')
    super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['contract'].queryset = Contract.objects.filter(customer__id=customer)
```